# Associate URL with Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: url, windows-phone-8.1

is it possible to associate specific URL with Windows Phone 8.1 application?
When there is a request to open URL in format e.g. http://myservice.mydomain.com?Params... from e-mail or page in browser, my application will process an URL.
On Android it is possible in manifest with intent-filter for some activity:

```
...
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="myservice.mydomain.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: as far as I know, you can associate a file format with your WP8.1 app, but no way can associate URL except IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an URI association with a custom URI schema, like "myapp:"
Read more here: [URI Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_URIassociations)